# Arduino as ISP - program is being uploaded on Arduino, not breadboard

Tags: atmega328, arduinoisp

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard), and have wired Arduino using this diagram:

[image]

This is what it looks like:

[image]

These options are selected in Arduino IDE:

[image]

This is the program I'm uploading:

```
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

When I upload it, it's uploaded on the Atmega on arduino board, not the one on breadboard. Both chips are ATMEGA328P.

I also tried to put 10μF capacitor between GND and RESET pins of the arduino board, which led to following errors:

```
Sketch uses 936 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.21.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.21.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Jakub\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_319338/BlinkTestAtmega.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.21.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM4
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x12
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Note that I have a homemade ATTINY programmer shield for this arduino board and it works without problems.

Comment: Do you have a capacitor on the RESET pin of the Arduino? From you image I'm not sure. You need it for preventing the Arduino to reset and start the bootloader, when the serial port is opened

Comment: I tried to put 10uF and 22nF capacitors there. With 10uF, I get a bunch of `avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync` errors, the 22nF cap has no effect.

Comment: @Juraj I don't understand. Are you saying the tutorial I am following is wrong? When I select "Burn bootloader" it finishes without errors, but I don't know if it actually does anythinh.

Comment: @Juraj I am running arduino IDE, I don't know how to access output other than what's available in the IDE.

Comment: sorry. Use the "Upload using programmer" in Sketch menu to upload a sketch over ISP

Comment: after uploading the bootloader, you have to remove the chip from the arduino and wire the tx/rx lines from the arduino to your bread board chip. Its mentioned in the second part of the link you have provide. Did you do that..?

Comment: @Juraj Awesome, it works fine. The older versions of Arduino IDE used the same button to upload using ISP. It kinda made sense in my opinion. After all, I already selected Arduino as ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "Upload using programmer" in Sketch menu to upload a sketch over ISP

[image]

warning, it deletes the bootloader